# Error when using JPGEncoder class in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm trying to use the JPGEncoder class in flash AS3 but this error keeps popping up (when testing):

```
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: BitString.
```

The problem line is in the JPGEncoder class, which I got from [here](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/blob/master/src/com/adobe/images/JPGEncoder.as):

```
private function writeBits(bs:BitString):void
```

Anyone know how I could solve this issue? Thanks xD

Comment: The link you provided the most resent commit was 2 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means it cannot find the BitString class.

Make sure you hve downloaded the [BitString class file](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/blob/master/src/com/adobe/images/BitString.as) and any other required classes. To be sure you might want to consider downloading the whole [as3CoreLib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/zipball/master) and unzipping it while preserving file structure into your code folder.

Make sure they are placed in the correct folder structure, such as `yourProjetRootFolder/com/ adobe/images/BitString.as` or if in a folder out side of the root make sure the path is included in your ActionScript 3 settings.